# SQL (MS-Access) - LEFT JOIN to show records in left table not in right table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables: A has 400000 records and B has 350000 records approximately.

I'm doing a LEFT JOIN to show the difference between both tables but the query returns 100000 approx.

This is my Not-In query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.[ID] = TableB.[ID]
WHERE (TableB.[ID] is null)
```

Is there something wrong or is it possible that the query returns more than the difference between the tables? Thanks

Comment: It's very normal for there to be a larger returned result than the difference of record record counts between the two tables.  Not only could there be records in `B` that aren't in `A`, but `A` could also have records that `B` doesn't have.  You should take a closer look at your data if you feel this is incorrect.  As written, your query looks fine.

Comment: Are you sure that all of your records from B exist in A?

Comment: I usually do a union between the two tables to check matches in both directions.

Comment: @Siyual I checked in the other direction using a RIGHT JOIN and the result showed that there're no records from TableB that aren't in TableA. It seems weird to me that this LEFT JOIN shows more results than the difference between the tables. I was trying to figure out if there was some other reason for this but I still don't understand completely.

Comment: @warty This might sound like a dumb question, but what did your RIGHT JOIN look like?  Especially when you're stumped, if that is part of your effort then you should show it also (not just state it in comments)... even if it seems trivial.  And don't just type it up here, rerun exactly what you post. Finally, if your RIGHT JOIN statement is indeed valid as you state, then TableB has **duplicate ID** values that all match TableA.ID values.  From the numbers TableB has at least 50,000 duplicate ID values. That doesn't make sense if ID is a unique primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You query shows rows from table A that do not have a match in table B.  If you want the differences you also need rows from Table B that do not exist in Table A.  You can do this with a union

```
SELECT *
   FROM TableA 
   LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.[ID] = TableB.[ID]
   WHERE (TableB.[ID] is null)
Union All
SELECT *
   FROM TableB 
   LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.[ID] = TableA.[ID]
   WHERE (TableA.[ID] is null)
```

EDIT:  This assumes similar table structures.  You may need to use column names rather than * in the select clause.

Answer (score -2):

Other than the difference, you might pull some rows from TableB where ID is really null, as equality doesn't work for null values.

So the correct way, as stated in the other answer, is to set the NULL condition as part of the ON clause, not WHERE

Comment: The `Null` condition is *intended* to be in the `Where` clause, as they're only wanting to select records that failed the `Outer Join` check.  Moving it into the `On` clause is *not* the solution (and would lead to zero results, since `A.Id = B.Id And B.Id Is Null` can never result in true.)

Comment: Access also limits what fields and conditions can appear in the join ON clause--it would return an error.

Comment: @Siyual : NULL produces inconsistent results when in an =, that is why the meaning is ambiguous

Comment: @CPerkins: You are right, I missed the (MS Access) part.